# How to edit excel file with large data using SXSSF change cell color

Tags: java, apache-poi, sxssf

I have read all previous ask question but there is solution I found.

[How to Edit existing large excel file with SXSSF Streaming api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58500415/how-to-edit-existing-large-excel-file-with-sxssf-streaming-api)

[How to write to an existing file using SXSSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029374/how-to-write-to-an-existing-file-using-sxssf)

I have a existing file which I required to update the content change cell color for some content.

I need to modify excel file with large data over 40,000 rows.

Steps done in below code.

- Create new file for Result, Copy file 2 for result to highlight not
  equal cell
- Create Workbook for 2 compare excel files Temp
- XSSFWorkbook XSSF cellStyleRed as  SXSSFWorkbook cannot have cellstyle  color
- keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
- compareTwoRows from both excel file not equal will change cellstyle color to red on Result file.

Problem is with below code Result file is blank there is no content. I understand my code
   is incorrect as SXSSFWorkbook is creating new sheet.

HOW CAN I update result file by change cell color?

```
    package pageobjects;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
    import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import org.testng.Reporter;

    import property.IHomePage;
    import utility.SeleniumUtils;

    public class Excelcom2try extends SeleniumUtils implements IHomePage {
            public static FileOutputStream opstr = null;
            XSSFCellStyle cellStyleRed = null;
            SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = null;
            SXSSFSheet sheet = null;
            SXSSFRow row3edit = null;
            SXSSFCell Cell = null;
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void compare() {
            try {
                    // Create new file for Result
                    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("\\\\sd\\comparisonfile\\ResultFile.xlsx"));
                    workbook.write(fos);
                    workbook.close();
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    // get input for 2 compare excel files
                    FileInputStream excellFile1 = new FileInputStream(new File("new File("\\\\sd\\comparisonfile\\UAT_Relationship.xlsx"));
                    FileInputStream excellFile2 = new FileInputStream(new File(""\\\\sd\\comparisonfile\\Prod_Relationship.xlsx"));
                    // Copy file 2 for result to highlight not equal cell
                    FileSystem system = FileSystems.getDefault();
                    Path original = system.getPath(""\\\\sd\\comparisonfile\\Prod_Relationship.xlsx");
                    Path target = system.getPath(""\\\\sd\\comparisonfile\\ResultFile.xlsx");

                    try {
                            // Throws an exception if the original file is not found.
                            Files.copy(original, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                            Reporter.log("Successfully Copy File 2 for result to highlight not equal cell");
                            Add_Log.info("Successfully Copy File 2 for result to highlight not equal cell");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Reporter.log("Unable to Copy File 2 ");
                            Add_Log.info("Unable to Copy File 2 ");
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    FileInputStream excelledit3 = new FileInputStream(new File("\\\\sd\\comparisonfile\\ResultFile.xlsx"));
                    // Create Workbook for 2 compare excel files
                    XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(excellFile1);
                    XSSFWorkbook workbook2 = new XSSFWorkbook(excellFile2);
                    // Temp workbook
                    XSSFWorkbook workbook3new = new XSSFWorkbook();
                    //XSSF cellStyleRed as  SXSSFWorkbook cannot have cellstyle  color
                    cellStyleRed = workbook3new.createCellStyle();
                    cellStyleRed.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
                    cellStyleRed.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                    // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook to compare both excel sheets
                    XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
                    XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook2.getSheetAt(0);
                    //XSSFWorkbook workbook3new temp convert to SXSSFWorkbook
                    // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
                    sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
                    sxssfWorkbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
                    sheet = sxssfWorkbook.createSheet();
                    // Compare sheets
                    if (compareTwoSheets(sheet1, sheet2, sheet)) {

                            Reporter.log("\\n\\nThe two excel sheets are Equal");
                            Add_Log.info("\\n\\nThe two excel sheets are Equal");
                    } else {
                            Reporter.log("\\n\\nThe two excel sheets are Not Equal");
                            Add_Log.info("\\n\\nThe two excel sheets are Not Equal");

                    }

                    // close files
                    excellFile1.close();
                    excellFile2.close();
            // excelledit3.close();

                    opstr.close();
                     // dispose of temporary files backing this workbook on disk

            }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Reporter.log("Successfully Close All files");
            Add_Log.info("Successfully Close All files");
    }

    // Compare Two Sheets
    public boolean compareTwoSheets(XSSFSheet sheet1, XSSFSheet sheet2, SXSSFSheet sheet) throws IOException {
            int firstRow1 = sheet1.getFirstRowNum();
            int lastRow1 = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
            boolean equalSheets = true;
            for (int i = firstRow1; i <= lastRow1; i++) {

                    Reporter.log("\n\nComparing Row " + i);
                    Add_Log.info("\n\nComparing Row " + i);
                    XSSFRow row1 = sheet1.getRow(i);
                    XSSFRow row2 = sheet2.getRow(i);
                    //row3edit = sheet.getRow(i);
                    for(int rownum = 0; rownum < 100; rownum++){
                            row3edit= sheet.createRow(rownum);
                    }
                    if (!compareTwoRows(row1, row2, row3edit)) {
                            equalSheets = false;
                            // Write if not equal
    // Get error here java.lang.NullPointerException for row3edit.setRowStyle(cellStyleRed);
                            //if disable test is completed Successfully without writing result file
                            row3edit.setRowStyle(cellStyleRed);
                            Reporter.log("Row " + i + " - Not Equal");
                            Add_Log.info("Row " + i + " - Not Equal");
                            // break;
                    } else {
                            Reporter.log("Row " + i + " - Equal");
                            Add_Log.info("Row " + i + " - Equal");
                    }
            }

            // Write if not equal
            opstr = new FileOutputStream(""\\\\sd\\comparisonfile\\ResultFile.xlsx");
            sxssfWorkbook.write(opstr);

            opstr.close();

            return equalSheets;
    }

    // Compare Two Rows
    public boolean compareTwoRows(XSSFRow row1, XSSFRow row2, SXSSFRow row3edit) throws IOException {
            if ((row1 == null) && (row2 == null)) {
                    return true;
            } else if ((row1 == null) || (row2 == null)) {
                    return false;
            }

            int firstCell1 = row1.getFirstCellNum();
            int lastCell1 = row1.getLastCellNum();
            boolean equalRows = true;

            // Compare all cells in a row

            for (int i = firstCell1; i <= lastCell1; i++) {
                    XSSFCell cell1 = row1.getCell(i);
                    XSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(i);
                     for(int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 10; cellnum++){
                             Cell = row3edit.createCell(cellnum);
                   String address = new CellReference(Cell).formatAsString();
                   Cell.setCellValue(address);
               }
                    if (!compareTwoCells(cell1, cell2)) {
                            equalRows = false;
                            Reporter.log("       Cell " + i + " - NOt Equal " + cell1 + "  ===  " + cell2);
                            Add_Log.info("       Cell " + i + " - NOt Equal " + cell1 + "  ===  " + cell2);
                            break;
                    } else {
                            Reporter.log("       Cell " + i + " - Equal " + cell1 + "  ===  " + cell2);
                            Add_Log.info("       Cell " + i + " - Equal " + cell1 + "  ===  " + cell2);
                    }
            }
            return equalRows;
    }

    // Compare Two Cells
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static boolean compareTwoCells(XSSFCell cell1, XSSFCell cell2) {
            if ((cell1 == null) && (cell2 == null)) {
                    return true;
            } else if ((cell1 == null) || (cell2 == null)) {
                    return false;
            }

            boolean equalCells = false;
            int type1 = cell1.getCellType();
            int type2 = cell2.getCellType();
            if (type2 == type1) {
                    if (cell1.getCellStyle().equals(cell2.getCellStyle())) {
                            // Compare cells based on its type
                            switch (cell1.getCellType()) {
                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                                    if (cell1.getCellFormula().equals(cell2.getCellFormula())) {
                                            equalCells = true;
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                    break;

                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    if (cell1.getNumericCellValue() == cell2.getNumericCellValue()) {
                                            equalCells = true;
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                    break;
                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    if (cell1.getStringCellValue().equals(cell2.getStringCellValue())) {
                                            equalCells = true;
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                    break;
                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                    if (cell2.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                                            equalCells = true;

                                    } else {
                                    }
                                    break;
                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                    if (cell1.getBooleanCellValue() == cell2.getBooleanCellValue()) {
                                            equalCells = true;
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                    break;
                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                                    if (cell1.getErrorCellValue() == cell2.getErrorCellValue()) {
                                            equalCells = true;
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                    break;
                            default:
                                    if (cell1.getStringCellValue().equals(cell2.getStringCellValue())) {
                                            equalCells = true;
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                    } else {
                            return false;
                    }
            } else {
                    return false;
            }
            return equalCells;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general 40'000 rows is a very small volume of data and I would not
like to suggest employing Streaming in that case.
Instead, you can hold 40'000 rows in a XSSF workbook easily if you just
provide enough memory. Using a XSSF workbook, you can modify the
content directly as you have tried.

However, if you work with really large data of 1 Mill. rows and many
columns, then the following approach will help:

1) engange the Excel Streaming Reader
2) read both files F1 and F2 simultaneously and compare row by row and
cell by cell
3) based on the found difference, create a new row with new cells and
write that to your result file F3

You can not modify existing cells in a SXSSFWorkbook.